# Space Complexity of Linked List by using pointer

Tags: javascript, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I have declared a class `Node` for creating new node in linked list like this:

```
class Node{
  constructor(data){
    this.data = data;
    this.next = null;
  }
}
```

Then I tried to iterate through the given `head` linked list and want to create a new linked list like this:

```
// head: 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> x

function doSomething(head){
  let linked_list = new Node(head.data);
  let linked_list_ptr = linked_list;
  let head_ptr = head.next;
  
  while(head_ptr !== null){
    linked_list_ptr.next = new Node(head_ptr.data);
    linked_list_ptr = linked_list_ptr.next;
    head_ptr = head_ptr.next;
  }
  
  return linked_list;
}
```

My question is that what will be the space complexity of this function or code? Because at first I am creating a single node and then using `pointer` to create new node and iterate through the linked list. I think the time complexity will be `O(n)` but what about the space complexity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I think the time complexity will be O(n) ...

That's right.

> ...but what about the space complexity?

It is also O() because your code constructs  times a `Node` instance with the `new` operator. The first one is created outside the loop, and the other −1 are created inside the loop.

The other variables, like `head_ptr`, `linked_list_ptr`, `linked_list` and `head` are all object references which require O(1) space, so in total the space complexity is O().

Side note: the function assumes the list is not empty. You'd need to cover the case where `head` is `null`.